# Need some help on RobotC coding

Tags: c, sensors, nxt, lego-mindstorms, robotc

I'm working on a project and I really need some help to understand how lego-temp.h works. I want to make a while loop so that I can measure the temperature while the robot is moving. The loop will stop when I'll find a temperature higher than the temperature that I have before the robot started moving.

I found out that I can read temperature with that command

```
LEGOTMPreadTemp(S2,temp);
```

This command is reading from the sensor `2`, my temperature sensor, and writes the result on a variable called `temp`.

My problem is that I can't find how can I read the temperature while the robot is moving. You can find the `lego-temp.h` on `\Sample Programs\NXT\3rd Party Driver Library\include` but I will post it as a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hGgO7TLDUYwKf8g9_g1mbNVCjsp-7iUU) if u can't find it.

Thank you for your time. :D

Comment: Simple question because I cannot see your link from where I am - as a test, could you stop the robot, then read, then start again real fast?

Comment: ALso similiar: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7822/how-do-you-program-mindstorms-to-keep-doing-a-task-until-either-the-ir-or-the-co

Comment: And http://www.mainerobotics.org/uploads/8/3/4/4/8344007/advanced_ev3_robot_programming.pdf

Comment: And finally, even closer to your questions: http://www.robotc.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3341  (Shows RobotC and multitasking)

Comment: Can you post the code you have done so far? Thanks

Comment: The code is this . https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GUnPmnFmNzu8caofTWzsWPPMWOQXW3wY

Comment: Michael if i do that start-stop thing how can i be able to always read while the robot is moving? 
I'm working on ur links right now!
Thanks for ur help.